# How to check which SMB Version is enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to find which version of SMB is enabled on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I used the following command in PowerShell to know the smb versions installed:

```
sc.exe qc lanmanworkstation
```

In its output, the `DEPENDENCIES` shows two versions of SMB:

- MRxSmb10
- MRxSmb20

Now the confusion is out of 2 versions installed, which SMB version is enabled on my server? As Server 2008 R2 does not support `Get-SMBConnection` I am unable to determine the specific version.

I have also check the registry path, and there is no entry about SMB version.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

Can anyone please tell me how to determine which SMB version is enabled on server if SMB versions are more than one?

Comment: This question is better suited for *https://serverfault.com/* as it does not contain any programming question.

Comment: Check here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84aa9472-630c-4cdb-939e-dfa5f406f473/need-to-check-smb-connection-version-on-windows-2008-r2-windows-7?forum=winserverfiles for answer. There is another link here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2696547/how-to-detect-enable-and-disable-smbv1-smbv2-and-smbv3-in-windows-and with more detail.

Comment: Since you are new here, please don't forget the accept your answer if it answers your question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question.  Since you found out that the `Get-SMBConnection` is not supported at win2008R2 the best way is to find out which drivers are running:

I have used our win2008R2 to check (see below example).  If you find out that the `STATE` is `4 RUNNING` than the version of smb is active and "running"

```
PS U:\> sc.exe query mrxsmb10

SERVICE_NAME: mrxsmb10
        TYPE               : 2  FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

PS U:\> sc.exe query mrxsmb20

SERVICE_NAME: mrxsmb20
        TYPE               : 2  FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER
        STATE              : 4  RUNNING
                                (STOPPABLE, NOT_PAUSABLE, IGNORES_SHUTDOWN)
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

That means that *both SMB* versions are active and running.

Comment: I tried to disable SMB1 using this cmdlet : Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" SMB1 -Type DWORD -Value 0 -Force
Then, I ran the cmd : sc.exe query mrxsmb10, still SMB1 is running and not disabled.
What can be possible reason for this?

Comment: @beginner I think the best approach would be to uninstall SMB 1.0/CIFS from windows features.